# Directly open ABPersonViewController in EDIT MODE DIRECTLY in iphone

Tags: iphone, edit, abpersonviewcontroller

I am developing address book app. When user selects a user from a contact list , I want to open that record directly in EDIT mode using `ABPersonViewController` instead of clickng Edit button of `ABPersonViewController`. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: did you have a look at this project- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call setEditing after the view is displayed:

```
ABPersonViewController *ab = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
ab.allowsEditing = YES;
// customize as you see fit
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ab animated:YES];
[ab setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```

I tried this on the iPad from within a popover controller and that works fine.

Comment: this does not work for me. I still get person details window with Edit button at top right

Answer (score 1):

In fact AB**New**PersonViewController  looks exactly like ABPersonViewController in edit mode.

Comment: Great solution! And you just change the ABNewPersonViewController.Title to whatever you like, rather than "New Contact".

Answer (score -2):

I accomplished the same by doing like this:

```
    ABRecordID personId = (ABRecordID)contact_ID;// if you want to edit a particular record and you're maintaining contact ID somewhere in your project.
    ABPersonViewController *contactVC = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    contactVC.personViewDelegate = self;// set your ViewController as delegate
    contactVC.allowsEditing = YES; //set NO if you don't wanna allow editing
    contactVC.displayedPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, personId);
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:contactVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```