# How to programmatically call ABPersonViewController edit view after loading ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This question is already asked but was still not answered. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315280/directly-open-abpersonviewcontroller-in-edit-mode-directly-in-iphone))

I have made a `UIViewController` that looks like `ABPersonViewController` view with some added buttons.

I also have the edit button at the right navigation bar that already have a function of calling the `ABPersonViewController`, I know it is possible to programmatically load the edit view of it but i just can't find the right code. (Viber does this)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check out the Apple sample code ? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Comment: Yep...It does have a sample of calling the `ABPersonViewController` with the edit button, but what i want to do is automatically click the edit button on its `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Edit button is just the standard

```
self.editButtonItem
```

Then that means that you probably have a UITableView and inside of the viewWillAppear method you can just call

```
[self setEditing:YES];
```

However, if the code has an Edit method, then just call that method from viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'am searching for this about 2 days now.

I would like to give you a vote up but i don't have the required reputation yet.

Comment: @Bryan That's fine, you can always come back when you have enough.  Glad to be of help!